# Google Maps SDK for iOS v1.2 markers not tappable

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've been using Google Maps SDK for iOS v1.1 without any problems, but just updated to v1.2 (and v1.2.1, released today). Now, when I create a GMSMarker, it can't be tapped to open the info window. The same also happens in the demo application bundled with the SDK, so I'm sure it's not just me.

I'm using the following code:

```
GMSMarker* marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(result.lat, result.lng)];
marker.title = result.shortName;
marker.tappable = YES;
marker.animated = YES;
marker.map = self.mapView;
```

I don't see what I could be doing wrong - it seems like a major issue with the updated SDK.
I've implemented all of the delegate methods on GMSMapViewDelegate, and I get nothing called when the marker is tapped.

Can anyone from Google Maps team help? Thanks.

Edit: I've done some further testing, and I believe that this is dependent on the orientation of the device!

1. Open SDK test application, 'Marker event' demo with device in portrait mode > Markers are tappable.
2. Open SDK test application, 'Marker event' demo with device in upside-down portrait mode > Markers are not tappable.

Comment: Seems to be already a reported bug: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5296

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed since version 1.2.2